# Simplify $(1-\sqrt{11}i)\sqrt{5-\sqrt{11}i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Simplify $(1-\sqrt{11}i)\sqrt{5-\sqrt{11}i}$

My solution:

By using half angle formula of the tangent function for the second number in the product we have
$\arg(1-\sqrt{11})+\arg(\sqrt{5-\sqrt{11}i})=\arctan(-\sqrt{11})+\arctan(-\frac1{\sqrt{11}})=-\frac{\pi}{2}$
and the magnitude of the number is
$$\sqrt{12}\sqrt{\sqrt{36}}=6\sqrt2.$$

So the number is $-6\sqrt2 i.$

Is my answer correct? Can you suggest a simpler way? Thanks.

Comment: Which square root is meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $5-\sqrt {11}i$ has $2$ square roots and we don't know which square root is meant. I assume that the square root can be both.

Here is an alternative solution:

\begin{align}
\left(1-\sqrt{11}i \right)\sqrt{5-\sqrt{11}i} &=\pm \sqrt {\left(1-\sqrt{11}i \right)^2\left(5-\sqrt{11}i \right) }\\
&=\pm \sqrt{\left( -10-2\sqrt{11}i\right)\left(5-\sqrt{11}i \right) } \\
&=\pm \sqrt{-2\left( 5+\sqrt{11}i\right)\left(5-\sqrt{11}i \right) } \\
&=\pm\sqrt{-2(36)} \\
&=\pm6\sqrt2 i
\end{align}

Comment: Nice answer, I like it (+1).

Answer (score 1):

$5- i \sqrt {11}$  has square roots, one of them  has positive real part. I looked for it in the form $a + b i \sqrt{11}$  on the off chance that $a,b$ might be rational.

$$  \left( a + b i \sqrt{11} \right)^2 = (a^2 - 11 b^2) + 2ab i \sqrt{11}  $$

so we need $a^2 - 11 b^2 = 5$  and $2ab = -1.$ Well, $4 a^2 b^2 = 1$ and $44 a^2 b^2 = 11,$ while $a^4 - 22 a^2 b^2 + 121b^4  = 25.$  Add, we see   $a^4 + 22 a^2 b^2 + 121b^4  = 36$   and, with real $a,b,$   that $a^2 + 11 b^2 = 6.$   Adding and subtracting, $2 a^2 = 11$ and $22b^2 = 1.$   We are taking $a>0,$  so $b < 0.$

$a = \sqrt {\frac{11}{2}}$   while $b = - \sqrt {\frac{1}{22}}.$

Finally we get

$$ a + b i \sqrt{11}  = \sqrt {\frac{11}{2}}- i  \sqrt {\frac{1}{2}} $$

As a result the quantity in the question is

$$  ( 1 - i \sqrt{11} )      \left( \sqrt {\frac{11}{2}}- i  \sqrt {\frac{1}{2}}\right)                  $$
which comes out